# Is it possible to build your TestCaseSource list inside SetUp using NUnit?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

Can I build my TestCaseData list in my SetUp? Because with this setup my test is just being skipped. Other regular tests are running just fine.

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class DirectReader
{
    private XDocument document;
    private DirectUblReader directReader;
    private static UblReaderResult result;

    private static List<TestCaseData> rootElementsTypesData = new List<TestCaseData>();

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        var fileStream = ResourceReader.GetScenario("RequiredElements_2_1.xml");
        document = XDocument.Load(fileStream);

        directReader = new DirectUblReader();

        result = directReader.Read(document);

        // Is this allowed?
        rootElementsTypesData.Add(new TestCaseData(result.Invoice.Id, new IdentifierType()));
        rootElementsTypesData.Add(new TestCaseData(result.Invoice.IssueDate, new IdentifierType()));
    }

    [Test, TestCaseSource(nameof(rootElementsTypesData))]
    public void Expects_TypeOfObject_ToBeTheSameAs_InputValue(object inputValue, object expectedTypeObject)
    {
        Assert.That(inputValue, Is.TypeOf(expectedTypeObject.GetType()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @IMil, the answer is No... that's not possible.

`TestCaseSource` is used by NUnit to build a list of the tests to be run. It associates a method with a particular set of arguments. NUnit then creates an internal representation of all your tests.

OTOH `SetUp` (and even `OneTimeSetUp` is used when those tests are being run. By that time, the number of tests and the actual arguments to each of them are fixed nothing can change them.

So, in order to do what you seem to want to do, your `TestCaseSource` has to stand on it's own, fully identifying the arguments to be used for the test. That's why NUnit gives you the capability of making the source a method or property, rather than just a simple list.

In your case, I suggest something like...

```
private static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> RootElementsTypesData()
{
    var fileStream = ResourceReader.GetScenario("RequiredElements_2_1.xml");
    document = XDocument.Load(fileStream);

    directReader = new DirectUblReader();

    result = directReader.Read(document);

    yield return new TestCaseData(result.Invoice.Id, new IdentifierType()));
    yield return new TestCaseData(result.Invoice.IssueDate, new IdentifierType()));
}
```

Obviously, this is only "forum code" and you'll have to work with it to get something that actually compiles and works for your case.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is impossible.

Methods decorated with `[SetUp]` are run before each test case.

This means NUnit will first build list of test cases, then run `Setup()` before each of them.

Therefore, your `Setup()` never gets called, and list of test cases remains empty.

Comment: Then how am I supposed to test whether `result.Invoice.Id` is the correct type? Do I create a test for every single property inside `result.Invoice`?

Comment: @Jordec depends on your goals. You may just test everything in one test case. It will be a bit harder to produce a list of errors; easier if you're ok with just failing on the first error.